# Twilio: Video call connecting device with computer through ngrok

Tags: android, video, twilio, ngrok

I follow the  [Twilio quickstart-android] [1]: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/quickstart-android
 when i put the identity that i give at this url :  **htp://0fd251a7.ngrok.io/video-quickstart-php-master/token.php** inside poupup (invite participant) 
and when i click send at the end of the screen show onLocalvideoTrackAdded and a black small squere at the end and closed about 30-40 sec.
at the url http://0fd251a7.ngrok.io/video-quickstart-php-master/ my camera is turn on and dont get any invitation from the request that i send from app.

and is a problem that **compile 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.12.2'** is at build.gradle(Module:app) in dependencies and not at build.gradle(project:video-quickstart-php-master_test)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

        allprojects {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
            }
        }

    /* i have comment this becouse give me an error at android studio that the build file my be a missing a gradle plugin. */

    //compile 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.12.2'
```

this is build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.twilio.conversations.quickstart"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
    compile 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.12.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```